# Cannot resolve constructor

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an error that I don't know why in my Galaxy Ace Samsung(Android 2.3.6) doesn't work but in my Motorola G (Android 4.4) works perfectly. The exception are so strange this is my code:

```
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.single_row_profession, cursor,from,to,0);

package com.orun.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.orun.database.DataBaseManager;
import com.orun.model.Profession;
import com.orun.s.SConnection;


public class ProfessionsActivity extends Activity {

public static SConnection sConnection;
public static DataBaseManager manager;
private static Cursor cursor;
private static ListView listView;
private static SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
private static EditText etSearch;
private static ImageButton btSearch;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_professions);
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.PREFERENCE_FILE_KEY), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Rol "+sharedPref.getString("ROL","Estudiante"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    manager = new DataBaseManager(this);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    etSearch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etSearch);
    new LoadTask().execute();
    cursor = manager.searchProfession(etSearch.getText().toString());
    int[] to  = new int[]{R.id.textCode, R.id.textName,R.id.textType};
    String[] from = new String[]{"_id","name","type"};
    try {
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.single_row_profession, cursor,from,to,0);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            new SearchTask().execute();
            adapter.changeCursor(cursor);

        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {}

    });
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ProfessionsActivity.this,PrincipalActivity.class);
            int codeProfession = Integer.parseInt(((TextView)(view.findViewById(R.id.textCode))).getText().toString());
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.PREFERENCE_FILE_KEY), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putInt("CODE_PROFESSION", codeProfession);
            editor.commit();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.professions, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private class SearchTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        cursor = manager.searchProfession(etSearch.getText().toString());
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
}

private class LoadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            sConnection = new SConnection();
            for(Profession p : sConnection.getPlansPreg())
                manager.insertProfession(p.getCode(),p.getName(),"PRE");
            for(Profession p : sConnection.getPlansPos())
                manager.insertProfession(p.getCode(),p.getName(),"POS");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Se han cargador todos los planes",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

}

The exception is: Cannot resolve constructor

```
'(Landroid/context/Context;ILandroid/database/Cursor;[Ljava/lang/String;[II)V
```

Comment: Constructor of which class? Looks like for the class has the api changed between Android 2.3.6 and Android 4.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor you are using was added in API level 11, so it's no wonder it doesn't exist in Android 2.3.6 (API level 10).

> public SimpleCursorAdapter (Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
> String[] from, int[] to, int flags) Added in API level 11
>
> Standard constructor.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> **context**    The context where the
> ListView associated with this SimpleListItemFactory is running
>
> **layout**     resource identifier of a layout file that defines the views for this list item. The layout file should include at least those named views defined in "to"
>
> **c**  The database cursor. Can be null if the cursor is not available yet.
>
> **from**   A list of column names representing the data to bind to the UI. Can be null if the cursor is not available yet.
>
> **to**     The views that should display column in the "from" parameter. These should all be TextViews. The first N views in this list are given the values of the first N columns in the from parameter. Can be null if the cursor is not available yet.
>
> **flags**  Flags used to determine the behavior of the adapter, as per CursorAdapter(Context, Cursor, int).

See [class reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html).